# shell scripting - Write in a file

Tags: shell

Shell scripting: I have below input file
Contents of `file1`

```
-bash-4.2$ cat file1
sample.1.17.10.tar
test.1.17.10.tar
work.1.17.1.0.tar
```

Need to get output as below

```
From : > cat file2

    sample
    test
    work

From :>cat file3

1.17.10
1.17.10
1.17.10
```

It should generate two files by stripping the name and value as mentioned

Comment: Are you expecting output of three files above into one file? or you are trying to concat content  of all tar files into file or you just need files name?

Comment: I have input as file1 -> output should be in file2 and file3

Comment: I just need the file names. not the content

Comment: You just need the names? You already have them, they are `file2` and `file3` surely?

Comment: Don't you want `1.17.1.0` generated from `work.1.17.1.0.tar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut and Rev Used as per the example.

```sh
$ cat test.test
sample.1.17.10.tar
test.1.17.10.tar
work.1.17.1.0.tar

# For Version
$cat test.test | rev | cut -d"." -f2-  | rev | cut -d"." -f2-  > file1
$ $ cat file1
1.17.10
1.17.10
1.17.1.0

# For Filename
$ $ cat test.test | cut -d'.' -f 1 > file2
$ cat file2 
sample
test
work
```